# Select-String Regex to find string between simple quotes

Tags: regex, powershell-4.0

I get the followings lines from an invoke-webrequest :

```
numVersion = 'v1.1805.24',
    if(numVersion!="#@numVersion@#" && numVersion!="v1.1805.24") {
```

From this extract, I only need to keep the numVersion Number between the simple quotes ==> `v1.1805.24`.

But I get as a result the all line:

```
numVersion = 'v1.1805.24',
    if(numVersion!="#@numVersion@#" && numVersion!="v1.1805.24") {
```

Here is the code:

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get
$split_string = $r.content -split "`n"
$raw_version = $split_string | select-string -Pattern 'numVersion' 
$raw_version -match '(.*?[^*])'
```

Comment: Try `$r.content -match "(?<=numVersion\s*=\s*')v[0-9.]+"`. The `$matches[0]` should hold the right value.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your feedback, badly, the $matches[0] return numVersion = '

Comment: Look [here](https://imgur.com/a/FKnL1tK), you must have failed to use my suggestion as I wrote it.

Comment: I forgot to add the = in my pattern. Now your code is working great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
$r.content -match "(?<=numVersion\s*=\s*')v[0-9.]+"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dnumVersion%5cs*%3d%5cs*%27%29v%5b0-9.%5d%2b&i=numVersion+%3d+%27v1.1805.24%27%2c%0d%0a).

Then, the value you need will be in `$matches[0]`. Or, you may also capture the text you need:

```
$r.content -match "numVersion\s*=\s*'(v[0-9.]+)"
```

Then, the value will be in `$matches[1]`.

**Pattern details**

- `(?<=numVersion\s*=\s*')` - a positive lookbehind that matches, but does not consume, `numVersion` and a `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces and then a `'`  char
- `v[0-9.]+` - `v` and then 1 or more digits or `.` chars. You may replace this pattern with a mere `[^']+` here, but it is less specific to the current task.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be:

```
$r.content -match  "'([\S]+)'"
```

The value with the quotes will be in `$matches[0]` and the value without the quotes will be in `$matches[1]`.

Comment: The `'([\S]+)'` is a less safe pattern in general. Even though it works for the exact OP string, if there is a `'...'` substring somewhere before `numVersion` it will be returned instead of what is expected.

Comment: Yes, it's not the safest one, it's just the simplest one for the given string.